# C# string contains daterange which should splitted into 2 dates

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying to solve a problem. I have a string filled with a date range in the following format "dd.MM.yyyy - dd.MM.yyyy".

```
var datest = shippeddaterange.Split(new char[] { '-' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
var startDate = DateTime.Parse(datest[0]);
var endDate = DateTime.Parse(datest[1]);
```

Now I want to split it into 2 variables, so I can use my Lambda Query which works fine. My 2 new variables should be named as `startDate` and `endDate`.

```
data.Container = db.Container
  .Where(a => a.ShippedDate >= startDate && a.ShippedDate <= endDate)
  .ToList();
```

If I compile the app, it gives me the error, that the array value is out of the index range

Comment: Then the `datest`-array contains only one item because the string doesn't contain a hyphen or only at the beginning/end of the string.

Comment: Or none at all. Check if the string even landed in your action.

Comment: Hmm I dont understand Tim.

This here would work perfectly Balazs:
var start = new DateTime(2010, 1, 1);
var endDate = new DateTime(2019, 1, 1);

Comment: Check the value of `shippeddaterange` via debugger. Post it.

Comment: @NinjaCoder: but what has that to do with your question?  `datest` is a `string[]`. If you'd use the debugger you'd notice that the array contains only a single string. Then you can't access the second. I've mentioned the reason in my last comment.

Comment: @NinjaCoder you need to do some defensive coding. Don't assume Goldilocks situation as you will be in for a rude awakening. If the input is bad, then there stands a chance that you wont end up with 2 items.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to do some defensive coding. Don't assume Goldilocks situation as you will be in for a rude awakening. If the input is bad, then there stands a chance that you wont end up with 2 items.

```
public PartialViewResult SearchData(shippeddaterange) { 
    data = new ContentViewModel();
    using (var db = new PLSDb()) {
        var datest = shippeddaterange.Split(new char[] { '-' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
        if(datest.Length == 2) {
            var format = "dd.MM.yyyy";
            var provider = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
            var startDate = DateTime.ParseExact(datest[0].Trim(), format, provider);
            var endDate = DateTime.ParseExact(datest[1].Trim(), format, provider);

            data.Container = db.Container
              .Where(a => a.ShippedDate >= startDate && a.ShippedDate <= endDate)
              .ToList();                
        }            
    }
    return PartialView(data);        
}
```

Comment: If I hover with the mouse over the SearchData (which has a red underline), the error tells me "not all code paths return a value".

Comment: Update the code in the question. It is very difficult to understand it when it is in the comments

Comment: You need something for the else condition (when datest.Length is not 2)

Answer (score 2):

This here works pretty nice. I will write into the method public ActionResult Index() that the data should get filtered before the filter gets in action. Thanks for the help!

```
    public PartialViewResult SearchData(string shippeddaterange)
    {            
        using (var db = new PCSDb())
        {

            var datest = shippeddaterange.Split(new char[] { '-' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
            if (datest.Length == 2)
            {
                var format = "dd.MM.yyyy";
                var provider = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
                var startDate = DateTime.ParseExact(datest[0].Trim(), format, provider);
                var endDate = DateTime.ParseExact(datest[1].Trim(), format, provider);

                var data = new ContentViewModel();

                data.Container = db.Container.Where(a => a.ShippedDate >= startDate && a.ShippedDate <= endDate).ToList();
                return PartialView(data);
            }
            else
            {
                return PartialView("NameOfANewView");
            }                
        }
    }
```